# Tabindex based on enter key by getting form elemens not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery, key, tabindex, enter

I have a form, and I am able to get all form elements through `serializeArray()`.
I want to `focus()` on form elements based on their tabindex value using enter key. Only if it has value in it or else focus on itself.

Little new to jQuery so if any mistakes...

```
$.fn.entertab = function()
  {

 var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
  var maxTabIndex = 20;
        var elements = this.serializeArray();
     $.each(elements, function(i, element)
        {

 this.keypress(function(e){ 
    var nTabIndex=this.tabIndex;
       var myNode=this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if(nTabIndex > 0 && key == 13 && nTabIndex <= maxTabIndex && ((!myNode.attr("disabled")) || (myNode.val == "")))
      {
   myNode.focus(); 
   }
   else
   {
   nTabIndex=this.tabIndex+1;
      myNode.focus();
   }
   });

     });
        }
  $("theform").entertab();
```

Comment: could you provide the HTML you're using? Till than a few suggestions: move var key... inside this.keypress function, use onload/ready state to launch the entertab(): $(function(){/*here the code*/}); and you're using "theform", that's not a tag name, if it's a class name then use $(".theform").entertab();

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this
HTML

```
<input id="122" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="1" /><br>
<input id="123" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="2" /><br>
<input id="124" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="4" />This input is hidden<br>
<input id="124" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="5" /><br>
<input id="125" class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="3" /><br>
<textarea class='TabOnEnter' tabindex="6">Hi, I am a test area</textarea>
```

SCRIPT
///////////

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".TabOnEnter" , function(e)
  {
    //Only do something when the user presses enter
    if( e.keyCode ==  13 )
    {
       var nextElement = $('[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex+1)  + '"]');
       console.log( this , nextElement ); 
       if(nextElement.length )
         nextElement.focus()
       else
         $('[tabindex="1"]').focus();  
    }   
  });

//Hidden inputs should get their tabindex fixed, not in scope ;)
//$(function(){ $('input[tabindex="4"]').fadeOut();  })
```

//////////////
Worked Fine in EI,Chrome, Mozilla . not tested in safari and other browser

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do. I rewrote your code and ended up with this:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.entertab = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            maxTabIndex: 20
        };

        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.filter('form').each(function(){

            var $this = $(this),
                $elms = $this.find("[tabindex]");

            $elms.each(function(){
                var $elm = $(this),
                    idx = parseInt($elm.attr("tabindex"));
                if (idx > options.maxTabIndex) {
                    return;
                }
                $elm.keydown(function(e){
                    if (e.which == 13 && ($elm.val() != '')) {
                        $elms.filter("[tabindex="+(idx+1)+"]").focus();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

There's a working example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/unCu5/).

Comment: @ullasvk, no problem but did this answer your question? If so, please accept this answer.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall It do works ,Plus one for that , The questioner must have marked this as answer :/

Comment: your jsfiddle only works by hitting "tab key" not "enter key"!!