# wanted to extend jQuery to handle a custom enter key event based on tabindex

Tags: jquery, key, tabindex, enter

I write the following code to handle when the enter key pressed an with few validation like if it is a textarea allow only four lines and if the value is empty, focus on itself.

```
var temp = 1;
 function getLines(id)
    {
      return temp=temp+id;
    }
$("#theform").keypress(function(e){
var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;                                
    if (key == 13) {
        var $targ = $(e.target);
        var tindex = $targ.attr("tabindex");
        var count =1;
        var focusNext = false;
        var allowedNumberOfLines = 4;
       if ($targ.is("textarea") && !$targ.is(":button,:submit")) {
          var lines= getLines(count);
            if (lines > allowedNumberOfLines)
            {
            $("#login_error").css('background', '#F7F77C').fadeIn(1000).html("Only "+allowedNumberOfLines+" Lines Allowed").fadeOut(1000);
            tindex++;
            $("[tabindex=" + tindex + "]").focus();    
            return false;
            }
        }
        else if($targ.val() =='' || $targ.val() == "undefined")
        {
        $("[tabindex=" + tindex + "]").focus();    
         return false;
        }
        else if($targ.val() !='' || $targ.val() != "undefined")
        {
        tindex++;
        $("[tabindex=" + tindex + "]").focus();    
         return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Is there any way to make it a custom function so that i can just call the function like

```
$('theform').returnPress();
```

Comment: What do you want returnPress() to do?

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632847/tabindex-based-on-enter-key-by-getting-form-elemens-not-working-in-jquery/4633758#4633758) earlier today. [Check it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/unCu5/)

This doesn't do any validation, but perhaps you can change it yourself.

Comment: Just for the record - the "similar question" you answered is from the same user as this one.

Comment: @Matt, haha. Just recalled the question, and didn't bother to check the user. Oh well, lesson learnt. Thanks for the heads up ;)