# How to change onfocus attribute with jquery according to tabindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setfocus, onfocus

I have a list of elements in my page which are ordered with tabindex. What I am looking for is how can I emulate that the tab key was pressed so the focus to move on the next element? I am planning to change focus on my elements in a specific time interval i.e. 1sec by using jquery.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632847/tabindex-based-on-enter-key-by-getting-form-elemens-not-working-in-jquery/4633758#4633758)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a[href="#your_tab"]').trigger('click')
```

Edit: 
I see you are trying to simulate `TAB` keypress not `click` mouseclick. This will help you I think: [Simulating a tab keypress using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702585/simulating-a-tab-keypress-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ropstah example but trigger the keypress event http://api.jquery.com/trigger/. You can specify which keycode you want "pressed"